How to build browser app that imports Hedera SDK JS?
I'm attempting to build an app that imports @hashgraph/sdk
bun build --outdir ./dist --format 'esm' --target 'browser' ./src/dapp.ts

However, I get the following error:
4 | import { Buffer } from "buffer";
             ^
error: No matching export in "node:buffer" for import "Buffer"
    at /Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-code-snippets/dapp-hedera-sdk/node_modules/@hashgraph/cryptography/src/primitive/aes.browser.js:4:10

How can I work around this?

More detail:
I've put the SSCCE to reproduce this at: https://github.com/hedera-dev/hedera-code-snippets/blob/feat/dapp-hedera-sdk/dapp-hedera-sdk/
I've also tried bun add buffer, which installs the buffer shim from npm, however, that results in the same error as above.

UPDATE:
I have updated the demo to include Giuseppe Bertone's answer.

I have updated the demo to include Giuseppe Bertone's answer. And gave this answer the checkmark. However, if there is another answer which solves this with bun build, happy to switch over the checkmark to that answer!

This issue does not seem to be a specific to the Hedera SDK JS.
Instead, it seems to be an issue with the build tool, bun.
Consider using a different build tool instead, such as webpack.
The tool vue-cli-service includes a build command that wraps webpack,
and is able to build this successfully.
Modify the package.json file from your SSCCE to include this command:
vue-cli-service build --dest ./dist --formats 'umd' --target lib --name dapp src/dapp.ts

Full file should look like this:
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run build-vue && npm run static && npm run serve",
    "static": "cp -r ./static/* ./dist/",
    "build-bun": "bun build --outdir ./dist --format 'esm' --target 'browser' ./src/dapp.ts",
    "build-vue": "vue-cli-service build --dest ./dist --formats 'umd' --target lib --name dapp src/dapp.ts",
    "serve": "npx http-server@14.1.1 ./dist -c-1 -p 8222"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hashgraph/sdk": "2.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "5.0.8"
  }
}

